# How to host Redmine on Dreamhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dreamhost, redmine

I was able to install redmine on dreamhost without any problems. I followed the directions from the dreamhost wiki and it is up and running. The problem is that it is very slow. So slow that it errors out sometimes. It gives a pipe broken error. Is there anything that can be done to improve the performance and eliminate the broken pipe errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're running Redmine on shared hosting, you should know that default amount of memory allowed is about 150Mb. Site running Redmine requires about the same amount, so sometimes passenger instance gets killed by system daemon for excessive memory consumption.

Comment: That would explain why I had so many problems. I ultimately stopped using Redmine because of the slow performance.

Answer (score 1):

are you using SVN if yes then please upgrade your version ?

Comment: Well that was unexpected. Upgrading from 0.9.3 to 0.9.6 seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: Still having issues and moved on to MantisBT. I didn't really need all of the features of Redmine and MantisBT is so much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in their wiki?

> This article describes how to install Redmine, an integrated Wiki and Issue Tracker with support for Subversion. These instructions assume you will be doing this on a shared host (DreamHost).
>
> http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Redmine

Comment: That is the guide I fallowed to install it.